# converting a onedimensional array to 2-d array having the specified number of columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i am passing one one dimensional array  having elements   "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
and in my code i want to convert this array into a 2-dimensional array .
The number of columns of the 2-d array will be specified by user .
say if am setting the columns value to 3

then the output 2-d array should be in the format

```
123
456
7
```

.m file of my class

```
-(NSMutableArray *)OneToTwoDimensionalArray:(NSMutableArray *)values :(NSInteger)columns
{
    NSMutableArray * twoDimensional=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:columns];
    for(int i=0;i<columns;i++)
    {
        [twoDimensional insertObject:values atIndex:i];
    }
    return twoDimensional;
}
```

viewcontroller.m file

```
   EPArray *arr=[[EPArray alloc]init];
    int columns=4;
    arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",nil];
    NSMutableArray *finalresult=[arr OneToTwoDimensionalArray:arr1 :columns];
    for(int i=0;i<columns;i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[finalresult objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
```

Comment: I mean the 2 d array shd contain user defined rows

Comment: You need to actually _ask_ a question. You've told us what you want to do, but nothing more.

What's wrong with the program at the moment? Are you getting incorrect outputs? We need more information.

Comment: @user2021210, Check my answer. Include that logic in your `OneToTwoDimensionalArray` method. Just replace `array` with `values`, `column` with `columns` and return the `outerArray` from that method.

Comment: @user2021210, Was my answer helpful? Can you please check and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
NSArray *array = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7"];
int noOfColumns = 3;

NSMutableArray *outerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int counter = 0; counter < [array count]; counter = counter + noOfColumns) {
    NSMutableArray *innerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int arrayIndex = counter; ((arrayIndex < counter + noOfColumns) && (arrayIndex < [array count])); arrayIndex++) {
        [innerArray addObject:array[arrayIndex]];
    }
    [outerArray addObject:innerArray];
}

NSLog(@"outerArray = %@", outerArray);
```

Here `outerArray` will give the 2 dimensional array with the provided column value. The above code is readable and easy to maintain especially if you want to make some quick changes.

**Output:**

```
outerArray = (
        (
        1,
        2,
        3
    ),
        (
        4,
        5,
        6
    ),
        (
        7
    )
)
```

Comment: @vikingosegundo, For a beginner I would always suggest to go with more traditional approach before they jump into advanced stuffs which uses blocks and all. From the question it is clear that OP doesn't have any expert knowledge in this language and for that matter I believe _this is more readable and maintainable_ for him.

Comment: I disagree: blocks are an important enhancement in apple's APIs. No user can have the luxury to not deal with them. This is true for beginners and professionals.

Comment: also if you really want to code with beginner's skill in mind, you should use a rows variable like Nathan in your outer loop, as this would be easier to read. `for (int i = 0; i< rows; ++i)` is much easier to read than `for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i = i + column)`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUInteger columnWidth = 3;
NSArray *array = @[@1, @2, @3, @4 ,@5, @6, @7];
NSMutableArray *mArray =[NSMutableArray array];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx % columnWidth == 0) {
        [mArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }
    [[mArray objectAtIndex:[mArray count]-1] addObject:obj];
}];
```

`mArray`now contains 3 arrays with

```
(
    (
        1,
        2,
        3
    )
,
    (
        4,
        5,
        6
    )
,
    (
        7
    )
)
```

This code uses the modulo operator that finds the remainder of division of one number by another.

```
if (idx % 3 == 0) {
    [mArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
}
```

if there is no remainder, it must be the index 0,3,6,…. In such a case, a new array is added to the outer array. the object are always added to the last array.

Also note that using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` should be faster than using c-style `for` (`for(int i=0;i<columns;i++)`) or even fast enumeration.

---

I added a [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14603298/106435) that uses only C-constructs rather than blocks, but I'd favor this one.

---

and — of course — you should consider using a category on NSArray

```
@interface NSArray (Columns)
-(NSArray *)arrayOfArraysWithColumnWidth:(NSUInteger)width;
@end


@implementation NSArray (Columns)
-(NSArray *)arrayOfArraysWithColumnWidth:(NSUInteger)width
{
    NSAssert(width > 0, @"width need to be 1 or greater");//sanity check
    NSMutableArray *mArray =[NSMutableArray array];
    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (idx % width == 0) {
            [mArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
        }
        [[mArray objectAtIndex:[mArray count]-1] addObject:obj];
    }];

    return mArray;

}

@end
```

You would use it like:

```
NSArray *numbers = [@[@1, @2, @3, @4 ,@5, @6, @7] arrayOfArraysWithColumnWidth:3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Next to my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599505/106435) — that I would favor — I want to offer another solution, that uses more traditional C-style programming but is quite readable.

```
NSUInteger columnWidth = 3;
NSArray *array =  @[@1, @2, @3, @4 ,@5, @6, @7];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger columnIdx = 0;
for (NSUInteger count = 0; count < [array count]; ++count) {
    if (columnIdx == 0) {
        [newArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }
    NSMutableArray *lastArray = [newArray lastObject];
    [lastArray addObject:array[count]];
    columnIdx = (++columnIdx)%columnWidth;
}
```

newArray now contains the subarrays as required.

note, that also this solution uses the modulo operator `columnIdx = (++columnIdx)%columnWidth;`.
instead of this you also could write

```
++columnIdx;
if(columnIdx == columnWidth) columnIdx = 0;
```